# Regarding user accounts, their gidNumbers, and SSSD requirement for a corresponding group with the same gidNumber(s)

Tags: nfs, sssd

If an LDAP user "Alice" has a gidNumber of 12345 and there is no LDAP group with the gidNumber of 12345, what are the implications with regard to sssd (System Security Services Daemon) and file system permissions for this user?

NetApp and Microsoft have stated for dual protocol NFS volumes that there is a requirement that a user account has to have a gidNumber and that this gidNumber must be resolvable to a group by sssd. What my group doesn't understand is if the group isn't actually used, why is it a requirement that it must be resolvable by sssd?

I can only surmise based on the info provided that it is a core function in sssd, is not negotiable, and will fail authentication for the user in some way if the group with the same gidNumber as set on a user account cannot be located. Is this correct?

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. If the NetApp has various volumes that may be exported to different systems and system A has group 12345 defined bur system B does not, what does NetApp do? The NFS server really should not care about resolving a gid to a name as the protocol transmits only the numeric gid.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/create-volumes-dual-protocol#manage-ldap-posix-attributes

Comment: I see this as a limitation of Azure only, not of NFS server platforms in general. We have NetApp, Isilon, Qumulo, Pure, and others in-house. Within the NFS protocol, only the gid number is transmitted in the metadata, translation to a name is left to the client. Dual-protocol shares are more difficult and could be considered and abomination but the NFS/CIFS platform still should not care.

Comment: Does adding `ldap_user_gid_number = uidNumber` in `sssd.conf` fix the problem in this specific case?

Comment: To be honest I couldn't say that there is a problem yet. The issue boils down to a directory synchronization, NDS -> Active Directory. NDS is the directory with the single source of truth and holds the POSIX attributes. For this dual mode file system, the specific requirements are that the POSIX attributes get written into the accounts in Active Directory as specified in the documentation I linked above. The point of contention is creating the groups that correspond to the gidNumbers, because in this case, 90% of the users have a unique gidNumber and associated group in NDS.